# How do I save state for bitmap images within GridView when orientation changes?

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-sharedpreferences

So I'm creating a sliding puzzle game application and currently populate a GridView with an array list of bitmaps which is created in the onCreate method of the activity. I then use Collections.swap in order to swap these images around, and then I reload my GridView to update the GridView on screen.

This works perfectly until the orientation of the phone is changed. The GridView images (puzzle tiles) returns to their starting posting (before the Collections.swap's).

I have been able to save the score on rotation by using SharedPreferences and this works perfectly. However, I don't know how to save Bitmaps or an ArrayList of bitmaps to SharedPreferences. Is there a way to do this? Or is there an alternative?

Comment: dont store bitmap if you dont want to got OutOfMemory exception, the first thing is thinking how to store link/path/url.. to that bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working for the change in orientation by creating an onSavedInstanceState method which saved my list array using state.putSerializable:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
    state.putSerializable(tileLocationsKey, puzzleTilesList);
}
```

I then checked if their were a saved instance state within my onCreate method by doing this:

```
if ((savedInstanceState != null) && (savedInstanceState.getSerializable(tileLocationsKey) != null)) {
    puzzleTilesList = (ArrayList<Bitmap>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(tileLocationsKey);
}
```

and if != null then it uses the saved list array.

Comment: How large are these `Bitmap`s? Under some circumstances (but _not_ when you just rotate your device), the `Bundle` that you write your information to will be passed to a binder transaction, and there are somewhat restrictive size limits on those.

Comment: Yes I've just noticed it doesn't seem to save properly if I exit the application and reopen it, however, it does work correctly when I rotate. How can I fix this?

Comment: The bitmaps differ in size as there is a bunch of them downloaded from a website and stored within an array

Comment: I assume you have some way of generating these bitmaps, right? Theoretically you do so when you first set up the board on a new game. What I'd do is save a list of bitmap _indexes_ instead of the bitmaps themselves, and then create a new game and reorder your list to match what was there before you rotated.

Comment: Also, `onSaveInstanceState()` is only applicable when the app isn't quit. It will let your data survive if the OS kills your process to conserve memory, but if the user quits the app from the "recents" screen, `onSaveInstanceState()` won't do anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help there. Any suggestions what I should use alongside/instead of onSaveInstanceState() then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167059/discussion-between-lnskip-and-ben-p).